# Convert Expression<Func<TInterface, bool>> to Expression<Func<TImplementation, bool>>

Tags: linq

Another Linq question =)

So I have a certain interface that I can code against and an expression that has this signature

```
 Expression<Func<TInterface, bool>>
```

At some point I will need to use that expression but it needs to look like this

```
 Expression<Func<TImplementaion, bool>>
```

I ve tried this

```
Expression<Func<TImplementation, bool>> expression = x => myExpression.Compile().Invoke(x);
```

And Although this compiles the expression gets lost in translatiion
Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK The BCL has very limited support for working with Expressions. I'm afraid that you're going to have to rewrite the expression yourself to change the method parameter type.

It's not hard, but not easy either. Basically, you will clone every node of the `Expression` (it's a tree) but set the root node's data type to your `Func<TImplementation, bool>`.

I would look for a different design that accomplishes the same goal but doesn't have this casting requirement - plowing through Expressions is not fun.

**Update** I've implemented a function that does what you want. I call it `CastParam`:

```
public static Expression<Func<TOut, bool>> CastParam<TIn, TOut>(this Expression<Func<TIn, bool>> inExpr) {
    if (inExpr.NodeType == ExpressionType.Lambda &&
        inExpr.Parameters.Count > 0) {

        var inP = inExpr.Parameters[0];
        var outP = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TOut), inP.Name);

        var outBody = inExpr.Body.ConvertAll(
            expr => (expr is ParameterExpression) ? outP : expr);                           
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<TOut,bool>>(
            outBody,
            new ParameterExpression[] { outP });
    }
    else {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

All it does is rewrite the expression substituting the old **ParamaterType** with the new type. Here is my little test:

```
class TInterface { public int IntVal; }
class TImplementation : TInterface { public int ImplVal; }

void Run ()
{
    Expression<Func<TInterface, bool>> intExpr = (i => i.IntVal == 42);
    Expression<Func<TImplementation, bool>> implExpr = intExpr.CastParam<TInterface, TImplementation> ();

    Console.WriteLine ("{0} --> {1}", intExpr, implExpr);

    var c = implExpr.Compile ();

    Console.WriteLine (c.Invoke (new TImplementation { IntVal = 41, ImplVal = 42 }));
    Console.WriteLine (c.Invoke (new TImplementation { IntVal = 42, ImplVal = 41 }));
}
```

As expected, it prints:

```
False
True
```

The code relies on an `Expression` rewriter that I wrote (rewrites expression trees from the bottom up):

```
public static Expression Rewrite(this Expression exp, Func<Expression, Expression> c) {
    Expression clone = null;
    switch (exp.NodeType) {
        case ExpressionType.Equal: {
            var x = exp as BinaryExpression;
            clone = Expression.Equal(Rewrite(x.Left,c), Rewrite(x.Right,c), x.IsLiftedToNull, x.Method);
            } break;
        case ExpressionType.MemberAccess: {
            var x = exp as MemberExpression;
            clone = Expression.MakeMemberAccess(Rewrite(x.Expression,c), x.Member);
            } break;
        case ExpressionType.Constant: {
            var x = exp as ConstantExpression;
            clone = Expression.Constant(x.Value);
            } break;
        case ExpressionType.Parameter: {
            var x = exp as ParameterExpression;
            clone = Expression.Parameter(x.Type, x.Name);
            } break;
        default:
            throw new NotImplementedException(exp.NodeType.ToString());
    }
    return c(clone);
}
```

The rewriter is obviously incomplete and you'll need to finish it off.

Comment: thanks for the quick answer, I was afraid of that :(. I ll live the question live for another while in case someone has some alternative ideas

Comment: Absolutely do. Also you can eventually set a bounty on it and maybe someone will write the code for you. :-)

Comment: Thanks for this I did something slightly different momentarily ( I have a private class that implements the interface and I recreate it from the setted properties. Its just a few lines of codes but I m not terribly happy with it so I ll have to revisit this after today ( small release today)

Comment: ConvertAll doesnt exist, am i missing something ?!

Comment: @Stacker I'm assuming you have already figured it out, given it's been nearly 7 years, but I'm pretty sure the `ConvertAll` is just the `Rewrite` function. That's at least what worked for me.